# Fair choice allocation using Edmonds Karp, adding group choices

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic-game-theory, fair-division

I have an algorithm that uses Edmonds-Karp algorithm to distribute users into groups in a fair manner given a rating for their choice of groups. Currently a given graph for two users ($u1$, $u2$) and two available choices ($c1$, $c2$) might look like this.

image of graph:
[image: Link to image of graph, sorry cant post images yet]

The weights on the edges represent the user's preference for the given choice. The shortest path is repeatedly searched until all users have been distributed. A distribution is represented by a path being chosen as the shortest. $(s, u1, c2, t)$ represents "user1" being distributed into "choice2".

Now I want to add the ability for users to make their choices in groups. My requirements for this are as follows:

1. Users that made their choice as a group should not have an advantage over users that did not
2. If there is space in a choice for a group, that choice should be preferred
3. If there is no space for a group, users of that group should be distributed individually, with the same weights as users without a group

My idea was to represent groups by user nodes being linked by an edge with weight $0$. So if "user1" and "user2" were in a group the graph might look like this.

[image: Graph with groups]

This was easy enough to implement and satisfies requirements $1$ and $3$, however it does not satisfy requirement $2$, as the individual paths have the same weight as those that go through multiple users.

How can I modify the graph in a way that satisfies all three requirements. Is this even possible? Help would be so greatly appreciated, I am really starting to doubt my sanity over this.

Update: I have managed to think of a solution using a graph with lower bounds, upper bounds and costs per edge. However now the problem has become finding an algorithm that can calculate the max flow for such a graph. The only one I found is the Out-Of-Kilter-Algorithm. I couldn't find any implementation for that one though, only this one https://github.com/MichalNowicki/NumericalAlgebraCodes which produces solutions that dont conserve flow (so basically, not solutions). Is there a better algorithm for this or implementations for that algorithm that work?